# Sequential Image fade from Images out of a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**My Goal:**

I want to fade each Image out of a folder. The Images change every once in a while. Is that even possible due to security reasons? The Site where the Images are displayed isnt public. It is just for a Xibo Digital Signage

**What I got so far:**

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kL6wbf38/)

*HTML:*

```
<div id="cf4a" class="shadow">
  <img src="images/4.jpg">
  <img src="images/5.jpg">
  <img src="images/4.jpg">
  <img src="images/5.jpg">
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
@-webkit-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 17% {
   opacity:1;
 }
 25% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 92% {
   opacity:0;
 }
 100% {
   opacity:1;
 }
}

#cf4a img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}

#cf4a img {
  -webkit-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;

  -moz-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-duration: 8s;

  -o-animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-duration: 8s;

  animation-name: cf4FadeInOut;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 8s;
}
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  -o-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4s;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
  -o-animation-delay: 0;
  animation-delay: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution could be to refresh the page every so often to pull the new images.

JS:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Is it even possible to have a changing amount of images then or do I need a fixed amount?

Comment: I guess this solution would be for using the same amount of images, and swapping out the images with the same file names. You'll probably need to use some other languages besides js/css if you're wanting to 'watch' a folder and display things from it. I probably couldn't help you there.